# Why does Firebase Database queryEqualToValue not work?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm constructing a a `FIRDatabaseQuery` with the following code:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let pointRef = ref.child("points")
let query = pointRef.queryOrderedByChild("location").queryEqualToValue(locationName)

query.observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    ...
}
```

The block is called, but I would like to order my results by another field in  each Point. As it's not possible to chain two `queryOrderedByChild`s together, I changed the code to the following (I would chain the ordering query later).

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let pointRef = ref.child("points")
let query = pointRef.queryEqualToValue(locationName, childKey: "location")

query.observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    ...
}
```

The block here is never called. Why not? I would expect these calls to be the same (apart from the first being sorted by location).

Comment: `let query = pointRef.child("location").queryEqualToValue(locationName)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I should be calling `observeSingleEventOfType` on the `pointRef`, not the `query` itself. The updated code:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let pointRef = ref.child("points")
let query = pointRef.queryEqualToValue(locationName, childKey: "location")

pointRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    ...
}
```

Although that doesn't explain why the first code does work, but the second doesn't.